# Android JSON to PHP Server and back

Tags: php, android, json

Can anybody offer a solution to the above?

For now, all i want to do is send a JSON request to my server (for example: {picture:jpg, color:green}), have the PHP access the database and then return a filename from the server's database (then get android to download the file - not an issue)

Can anybody suggest firstly an Android Framework that will help me with this. - POST JSON to a php file on my server

And secondly a php script that will turn the JSON into php readable format (accessing the database is not an issue either but i cannot get the JSON into an object to then match with the database)

thanks

**EDIT**

Thanks for the links below but i'm not asking this out of laziness, it's out of annoyance at my seeming inability to send a JSON string and get out the correct answer.

So let me show some code and find out why what i think should happen isn't happening:

GET URL (Using GET so i can show the working)

```
http://example.com/process/json.php?service=GOOGLE

<?php

// decode JSON string to PHP object
$decoded = json_decode($_GET['json']);

// I'm not sure of which of the below should work but i've tried both.
$myService = $decoded->service; //$service should equal: GOOGLE
$myService = $decoded->{'service'}; //$service should equal: GOOGLE

// but the result is always $myService = null - why?


?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Comment: OK, fixed the PHP side. For some reason, having  post_max_size = 10M in the php.ini was stopping the small amount of POST data (not GET) getting through.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, i've got the PHP. The below retrieves POST ed data and returns the service

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($data);
$service = $json->{'service'};

print $service;

?>
```

and the Android Code:

in onCreate()

```
path = "http://example.com/process/json.php";

    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
                                                                            // Limit
    HttpResponse response;
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(path);
        json.put("service", "GOOGLE");
        Log.i("jason Object", json.toString());
        post.setHeader("json", json.toString());
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,
                "application/json"));
        post.setEntity(se);
        response = client.execute(post);
        /* Checking response */
        if (response != null) {
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); // Get the
                                                                // data in
                                                                    // the
                                                                    // entity
            String a = convertStreamToString(in);
            Log.i("Read from Server", a);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and where ever you want

```
private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On the PHP side, all you need is the built-in [json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode), which will deserialize your json and return an object (or an associative array if you pass `true` as the second argument).

On the Android side, you'll probably use the [HTTP Libraries](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/package-summary.html) to execute your HTTP request and process the response.  (But someone who's actually developed for Android might correct me)