# Send json from android - server side

Tags: android, json, parsing

I need php script for server side to read json sent from android and to update database with received data. 
Can anyone help me? I don't know php to much, but need script for yesterday;) Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685534/android-json-to-php-server-and-back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decode the json String into an Object with the php function json_decode
http://www.php.net/json_decode

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['parameter']) {
    $json = json_decode($_REQUEST['parameter']); // gives you a php object
    var_dump( $json );
}
else 
    echo "No data received."
?>
```

Comment: And since the json_decode gives you an object, you could easily create a database query out of it. 
$query = "INSERT INTO table (FOO) VALUES (" . $json->bar . "...)";